# Dagger2 can't inject field inside injected class

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, inject

I was trying to playaround with dagger2 but I got problems with field injection, and here is my code.

POJO classes :

```java
// User.java
public class User {
    private String firstName, lastName;
    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

The class which I can't inject the `user` field.

```java
//BackendService.java
public class BackendService {
    @Inject
    public User user; // Not injected -> Null

    @Inject
    public BackendService() {
    }
}
```

User provider class

```java
// UserModule.java
@Module
public class UserModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    User providesUser() {
        return new User("AA","BB");
    }
}
```

Backend provider class

```java
// BackendServiceModule.java
@Module
public class BackendServiceModule {
    @Provides
    BackendService provideBackendService() {
        return new BackendService();
    }    
}
```

And last but not least, the component

```java
// ApplicationComponent.java
@Component(modules = {UserModule.class, BackendServiceModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    BackendService provideBackendService();
    void inject(ConsumerMain consumerMain);
}
```

The problem is that in `BackendService.java` the field `user` doesn't get injected.

Injection is working properly on `BackendService`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete your `@Provides BackendService` method.

When you call `new BackendService()`, you're telling Dagger "don't worry about how to create a BackendService, I can do it for you". That also prevents Dagger from calling `@Inject`-annotated constructors and methods, or populating `@Inject`-annotated fields.

When you delete that method, Dagger will inspect BackendService to learn how to instantiate it itself, at which point it will see your `@Inject` constructor and field and use them to construct a BackendService when needed.

Comment: That solved my problems, thanks for illustrating the issue :-)